# How to use mit-ros-pkg without ni?

Tags: ros, openni, mit-ros-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to use mit-ros-pkg (finger detection/minority report interface) under Ubunt11.10, ROS Electric, but it won't work.
Since this package said in its doc that it would work under Ubuntu 10.04, ROS DiamondBack, So I installed these on another PC. But the package uses NI for kinect driver, and I can't download ni.rosinstall, the file does not exist anymore.

I think the finger detection feature is pretty useful, so I want to know how to use this package under electric & openni? or, if it's too hard to transfer it to electric, please tell me how to use it

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28914/how-to-use-mit-ros-pkg-without-ni?/) by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2012-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the ni wiki page indicates, the ni stack has been replaced with:

http://ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect

However, there's been a lot of development since the original mit-ros-pkg demo was written, so you will likely have to port the code appropriately to handles changes to the OpenNI and PCL APIs.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) on 2012-03-02**:
Thanks for your answer. I'd like to modify the code myself, but before I do that, I want to make sure that nobody does it before. Do you happen to know the content of ni.rosinstall ?

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-03-02**:
ni.rosinstall just contained the (outdated) ni stack.  Thus, all you need to replace it is the openni_kinect stack, though the APIs have changed.

**Comment by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) on 2012-03-23**:
I managed to run the demo on Ubuntu11.10 and electric, thanks for you help